# How to fetch id of video from embed code?

Tags: javascript

I have two div I want to fetch the **video id** from embed tag of (div id="main)) through JavaScript. After that I want to replace that id with the embed code of (div container).

```
 <div id ="container">


     <object width="550" height="550">
          <param value="http://www.youtube.com/v/sIFYPQjYhv8&amp;rel=0&amp;color1=0x2b405b&amp;color2=0x6b8ab6&amp;border=1" name="movie">
         <param value="transparent" name="wmode">
         <embed width="550" height="550" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/sIFYPQjYhv8&amp;rel=0&amp;color1=0x2b405b&amp;color2=0x6b8ab6&amp;border=1">
       </object>
< /div>

<div id="main">
<a id="displayText">
<object width="150" height="150">
 <param value="http://www.youtube.com/v/sIFYPQjYhv8&amp;rel=0&amp;color1=0x2b405b&amp;color2=0x6b8ab6&amp;border=1" name="movie">
  <param value="transparent" name="wmode">
 <embed width="150" height="150" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/sIFYPQjYhv8&amp;rel=0&amp;color1=0x2b405b&amp;color2=0x6b8ab6&amp;border=1"></object>
  </a>
  </div>
```

Actually I have 5 video in `<div id="main">` when I click on any then that viedo should be play `<div id ="container">`.

Comment: do u know about jquery ? if not jquery.com and that would change your life forever :)

Answer (score 0):

try:

x = document.getElementByTag('div');

if (x.id == 'main')

{

do whatever

}

Ok...

x = document.getElementByTag('param')

if (x.name=='movie')

{

```
name = x.value;
```

}

Comment: I know this but I don't know how to got video id.